# put text to right to an image

Tags: html, css

How can I put a text to the right to an image, to look like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/brglg.png . I have tried with clear, float..a lot of commands..but for me, it doesn't work..

[image]

Can u help me please? Thanks :)
Here is my code:

```css
#subcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: red;
}
.person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35%;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  clear: right;
  float: left;
}
.group2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.person2 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35%;
}
.textwrap {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="subcontent">
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person2">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float` and changed some `%` ofsize in `width`

```css
#subcontent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
    background-color: red;
}

.person {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
   
}
p{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.group2 {
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
.person2 {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;  
}
.textwrap {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subcontent">
<div class="group2">
<div class="person">
<img  class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">
 
  <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others.

 Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
 </div>

<div class="person2">
<img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">
 
  <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others.

 Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `float` from content. and it will work.

```css
#subcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: red;
}
.person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
.group2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.textwrap {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subcontent">
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#subcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: red;
}
.person {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  clear: right;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 2%;
  width: 48%;
}
.group2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.person2 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.textwrap {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="subcontent">
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person2">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues. First of all, css classes are intended for **re-use**, so no need for a `.person2` class that has exactly the same rules as `.person`. Then, your code smells of desperate tries to achieve the desired effect, so it had far to many unnecessary statements. Third, please understand that stating `width` in percent always refers to the width of the parent element, so if your parent element has `width: 70%;` and you want to evenly divided child elements inside, you need to set child element's width to 50%, not 35%.

You should be able to get started from here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#subcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: red;
}
.person {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.textwrap {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
#subcontent:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="subcontent">
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person">
      <img class="textwrap" src="http://i.imgur.com/zzqeeyc.png">

      <p>A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. Jane Goodall - Residential Customer</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you're curious as to what that `box-sizing: border-box;` does, [please read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Also, I applied the "latest" version of the so-called [micro clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to clear the floats on `#subcontent` container.